# Rails installation on hostmonster bundle install fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rubygems

So I had a rails app up and working on my hostmonster account just fine. I then updated a few things in my dev environment / pushed them up to github / pulled them back down on my production environment. Now its giving me the error `Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`.

This is a new gem i installed in my dev because i was attempting to move to postgresql for dev and live....for now im using postgresql in dev and mysql2 in production. I know this isn't optimal but im working on it.

I tried running `bundle install` to get the pg gem installed and it fails with the error

`Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/cache/rake-10.2.2.gem] in /home4/muscorei/workspace/vollapp
An error occurred while installing rake (10.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install rake -v '10.2.2' succeeds before bundling.`

I try installing rake and it works fine...try again..same error. I have found one question on here that seems to fix this for others but it requires running of `gem update --system` which you cannot do for hostmonster. Any ideas?

So here is another "related" issue. When i type in gem list --local I see that rails is installed at version 4.1.0....however when i do rails -v it shows the systemwide version of 3.2.13. I don't EVER have any of these annoying issues on my dev environment.